How to transfer SOL to remaining_accounts from the signer account
I am trying to transfer 0.1 SOL from the signer account to all the accounts passed in the remaining_accounts to the function call. Here's a breakdown of the code.
anchor

    pub fn purchase_package(ctx: Context<PurchasePackage>) -> Result<()> {
        let total_amount: u64 = ctx.accounts.user.to_account_info().lamports();
        let LAMPORTS_PER_SOL: u64 = 1_000_000_000; // Number of lamports in one SOL
        let transfer_amount: u64 = LAMPORTS_PER_SOL / 10; // 0.1 SOL in lamports

        for i in 0..ctx.remaining_accounts.len() {
            let account_info: &AccountInfo = &ctx.remaining_accounts[i];

            if !account_info.is_writable || account_info.is_signer {
                return Err(ErrorCode::InvalidAccount.into());
            }

            let transfer_instruction = system_instruction::transfer(
                &ctx.accounts.user.key(),
                account_info.key,
                transfer_amount,
            );

            // Use a more explicit invocation pattern
            invoke(
                &transfer_instruction,
                &[
                    ctx.accounts.user.to_account_info(),
                    account_info.clone(), // Cloning here to get a new reference
                ],
            )?;

            distributed_amount += transfer_amount;
        }

        Ok(())
    }

The Javascript to call this function:
const response = await program.methods.purchasePackage().accounts({
          user: wallet.publicKey,
          systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
          lpWallet: lpWallet,
    })
    .signers([wallet.payer])
    .remainingAccounts(referralChainArray.map((referral) => ({
      pubkey: referral,
      isWritable: true,
      isSigner: false
    })))

When I build the anchor contract, I get error saying:
ctx.accounts.user.to_account_info()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^argument requires that `'2` must outlive `'1`

I also tried passing the clone() of the account, but the error still persists.

This is a Rust issue. There isn't enough information given about the error in the question, but I think it might be borrowing parts of ctx.accounts.user: using key() and to_account_info().
Try changing the instruction creation to the following:
            let user_key = ctx.accounts.user.key();
            let transfer_instruction = system_instruction::transfer(
                &user_key,
                account_info.key,
                transfer_amount,
            );

